# Suggestion how to update old table old field with new table new id field

Tags: database, ms-access

i have costumer and barcode table that keep costumer and shopping information. and now i need add another table that keeps their company infos. already done with this but now i need to add new field for the companyID and update this

i had a field for company names in my old table. how to replace the name with the new companyID on the new table.

Comment: please post your table definitions (CREATE TABLE ...).

Comment: Why not just keep the company names in the and add the companyID field.  I mean nothing wrong with having the company name and the ID.